# tautology (p→(q→p))

Tags: logic

A beginner's question:

This following formula is supposed to be a tautology:

(p→(q→p))

Meaning that for the following values

p=T
q=F

it's also supposed to hold.

I'm having trouble understanding how

q→p

is T?

I apologize for the basic nature of this question and if I had missed it's treatment/resolution somewhere else. Thanks for your help!

Comment: By definition $q\to p$ is false *only* when $q$ is true and $p$ is false. It’s automatically true, therefore, when $p$ is true.

Comment: My pleasure. $\,$

Answer (score 1):

$$
p\rightarrow(q\rightarrow p) \equiv \neg p \lor (\neg q \lor p) = (\neg p \lor p) \lor \neg q \equiv T \lor \neg q \equiv T  \mbox{ (tautology)} 
$$